# Unable to install http server using terraform ec2 instance -Error: Invalid function argument

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

```
on main.tf line 54, in resource "aws_instance" "http_server":
```

│   54:     private_key = file(var.aws_key_pair)
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.aws_key_pair is "~\aws\aws_keys"

```
Invalid value for "path" parameter: no file exists at ~\aws\aws_keys; this function works only with files that are
```

│ distributed as part of the configuration source code, so if this file will be created by a resource in this
│ configuration you must instead obtain this result from an attribute of that resource.

Comment: On what operating system is that path supposed to be valid?

Comment: Can you try to give full path instead of ~ ?

Comment: when i give full path .. iam end up with the below error 
Error: Invalid function argument
│
│   on main.tf line 49, in resource "aws_instance" "http_server":
│   49:     private_key = file(var.aws_key_pair)
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.aws_key_pair is "D:\\devops-master-class-master\\Terraform\\05-ec2-instances\\~\\aws\\aws_keys"
│
│ Invalid value for "path" parameter: failed to read
│ D:\devops-master-class-master\Terraform\05-ec2-instances\~\aws\aws_keys.